# Display the loaded tiles with out cropping in leaflet boundary canvas

Tags: leaflet, boundaries

I am using boundary canvas plugin to display the tiles belongs to polygon drawn area.

Presently tiles outside the polygon boundary is getting cropped while adding to map. But I wanted to display the complete tile without cropping.

```
  var newLayer = L.TileLayer.boundaryCanvas(tileProxy_url, {
                                        boundary: geojson,
                                        name: "newlayer",
                                    });

             drawnLayers.addLayer(newLayer);
```

Is there any option available to add the complete tiles intersecting the polygon boundary to the map?

Comment: Leaflet plugin `leaflet-boundary-canvas` has no such option. To achieve desired effect you would have to modify plugin code.

Comment: Thankyou  TomazicM, but i am very new to leaflet and i am facing difficulty understandg the plugin to do modifications . could some one help me on this?